# Back into first activity after "Force close"

Tags: java, android

I have created very simple project that contains 3 activities.

activity 1 have a button can go to activity 2

activity 2 have a button can go to activity 3

activity 3 have a button crash

on a crash button and I try set `throw exception`

```
buttonCrash.setOnclickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
});
```

After crash I click re-open, and activity go back to activity 2. how to every crash the app will restart or clear activity stack?

I try to make handle exception class:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  private Activity activity;
  public MyExceptionHandler(Activity a) {
    activity = a;
  }
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("crash", true);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
    activity.finish();
    System.exit(2);
  }
}
```

But it's suddenly restart the app, even though I need to show crash dialog first so I can click re-open to open again.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you intend to do here but have you tried *finishing* the "second" activity?

Comment: I update the post

Comment: have you tried *finishing* the second activity?

Comment: how to finishing when detected crash?

Answer (score 2):

try define your mainactivity home and default. add below code in intent-filter in activity in manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Activity clear task flag in every activity transition.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,yourclass.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add finish() function in your second activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using checking pass through on activity 1

```
public static boolean DOING_PASS = false;
```

set `DOING_PASS` is true inside `onStart` on `activity 1`

```
@Override
void onStart(){
    DOING_PASS = true;
}
```

so You can checking on every activity except activity 1 inside `onCreate`

```
if(Activity1.DOING_PASS){
    // do normal
}
else{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP || Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK || Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```